# Best way to store login information in iDevices?

Tags: ios

Hey,
what would be the best way to store login information (email, encrypted password) in my app for the iPhone, iPod and iPad devices to make a 'remember me' option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Keychain services are what you're looking for:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html